# When all tangent lines of a curve pass through a fixed point, the curve is a straight line?

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that when all tangent lines of a curve pass through a fixed point, the curve is a straight line. I thought the following:

We differentiate $x(u)$ and obtain $x'(u)=\lambda t(u)$ and then we have that for all $u$, there exists $\lambda$ such that $x'(u)=\lambda t(u)=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$. Integrating this, we obtain:

$$x(u)=(p_1u+c_1,p_2u+c_2,p_3u+c_3)=u(p_1,p_2,p_3)+(c_1,c_2,c_3)$$

Which is the equation of a line. Is my attempt correct?

Comment: No. The tangent line has to pass through $x(u)$. Also, forget coordinates and just work completely with vectors as vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried to think about it but couldn't write anything decent. In the book, there is a hint: Differentiate $x=\lambda t$ but It's not clear what I can do with this.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Let’s say all the tangent lines pass through the origin. And let’s assume, as always in these proofs, that $x$ is arclength-parametrized. Then there is a function $\lambda$ so that
$$0=x-\lambda T.$$
Now differentiate and use the obligatory Frenet equations.

Comment: I think I did it:

$$x=\lambda t \\ x' = \lambda't + \lambda t' \\ x'=-\lambda t'+\lambda t' =0$$

Is it correct?

Comment: @RedBanana No. where did the last step come from? You ignored the most important part of my hint. You *must* use Frenet.

Comment: Then I'd get

$$x=\lambda t \\ x' = \lambda't + \lambda \kappa n $$

But it's not clear what to do from here.

Comment: You have not used all the information. What is $x’$ called?

Comment: This is something that gets me a bit confused: $x'$ is the derivative of our curve $x(u)$, right?

Comment: If you’re not learning from Struik, read my book seriously and study both the examples and the proofs.

Comment: As the curve is arclength-parametrized, then $x'=t$? Is that it?